# React Slick slickSetOption

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I am using React-Slick (https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) for my project.
I want to be able to dynamically change the settings that I provide to my slider.

For slickjs (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) this can be done using `slickSetOption`.

I realized that this is not possible in React Slick after reading documentation.
The following was also posted by one of the contributors to the plugin:

> slickSetOption will not be implemented, those effects be achieved by
>   passing props via state from the wrapper component

This made me think that it *should* be possible to in fact change the settings of the slider in a dynamic way.

My implementation looks like this

```
<Slider
    dots={true}
    infinite={true}
    speed={500}
    slidesToShow={1}
    slidesToScroll={1}
    autoplaySpeed={2000}
    autoplay={props.autoplay} // even if the value is changed, autoplay stays to it's initial setting
>
    {images}
</Slider>
```

Using React Slick's playground I've put together this to demonstrate the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-unyot

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the component, probably some internal state is not changed. As a workaround, you can change the `key` prop when the `autoplay` prop change, this will force the `Slider` component to be recreated :

```
  state = {
    dots: true,
    autoplay: false,
    sliderKey: Date.now()
  };

  useAutoplay() {
    this.setState({
      autoplay: true,
      sliderKey: Date.now()
    });
  }


  <Slider key={this.state.sliderKey} {...this.state}>
  </Slider>
```

Complete code : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-dx957